# Case insensitive string search

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-3.5

What is the quickest most efficient way to search text for words using non-casesensitive search.

E.g here is my text to be searched :

```
string textTosearch = "Here is a paragraph or Some text. Here is some more text".
```

If I wanted to find the indexes of "Some" and "some", is there a .Net class that does this or would I need to use something like regular expressions.

Your thoughts are much appreciated.

I'm using visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425.aspx) method:

```
textTosearch.IndexOf("some", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

[Other overloads of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224423.aspx) allow you to specify a start index and a number of characters to examine.

Comment: I was just doing some tests, and found that given both large and small amounts of text that Text.ToLower().Contains(Value.ToLower()) is quite a bit faster for case insensitive searching than the indexOf method.  Maybe there is some drawback to doing it this way though that I am not aware of.